# Initiate Toolbar setScrollOffUponContentPane() with a seperate container

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a borderLayout form with Tabs at the center that contains scrollable containers and I want when user scrolls any of the containers in the tab, to pull up and down the Title bar.

This is possible if my ContentPane is scrollable and none of my inner container is, but making my contentPane scrollable will hide my tabs upon scrolling and ruin user experience.

I extended Toolbar to create a custom Toolbar but bindScrollListener() is private and can't be overridden.

Is there a way to modify Toolbar to allow setScrollOffUponContentPane() to be initiated by 2 or more scrollable containers working asynchronously?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question, are you trying to do something like this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-animation-manager.html

Comment: BTW I recommend always tagging Java too in order to get syntax highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available as part of the new `AnimationManager` class and new animation framework announced [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-animation-manager.html).

This should be a part of the new plugin and should already be usable with the source distribution as its already committed to github.

While we might manipulate the API a bit as we are growing it, we think we already have a relatively good direction and any changes should be quite minimal.